# How do you create an XML payload from a database table for Post and Put calls to RESTful API?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, api, rest

I'm working with a Rails application that currently just makes get calls to an external RESTful API and parses the XML data received to store them in a local database. This application also needs to be able to make post and put calls to the external API with XML payloads.

We need to create several of these payloads (for different calls) from different database tables. How would one go about automating the process of creating the XML payload to use them as part of the POST and PUT calls?

*Working with: Ruby on Rails, XML, MySql, and external RESTful API*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [excellent HTTParty library.](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

This answer here provides a good example of how to do it, I'll try to summarize theirs with some code. You want to do something like this:

```
require 'httparty'
class Webservice
  include HTTParty
  format :xml
  base_uri 'mysite.com'
  default_params :authorization => 'xxxxxxx'

  def self.add_candidate(candidate_hash={})
    post('/test.xml', :body => candidate_hash)    
  end  
end
```

where the candidate_hash can look like this:

```
  :Candidate => {
    :FirstName => first_name,
    :LastName  => last_name,
    :Email     => email,
    :Gender    => gender,
  }
```

Essentially, HTTParty will take the Ruby hash and automagically convert it to XML (or JSON) if you prefer before it posts/puts